# How to make click event in ajax form button through jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

Iam getting form through ajax in existing page. when iam going tomake click event on button through jquery its not working

Iam making onchange event based on that value iam getting results through ajax in existing in that form i have one button. iam trying to make click event in existing page with jquery
 like

```
<button class="del" value="2">   Delete  </button>
```

This button is coming from ajax so is it possible to make click event like.
button class name is del

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".del").click(function(){   
        alert($(this).val());   
    });   
});
```

through javascript i can make like this

```
onclick="javascript:delete()"  

<button class="del" onclick="javascript:delete()" value="2">Delete</button>
```

Is it possible to make click event on ajax button through jquery ?
    I used on(click) also but its not working

```
$(".del").on("click",function(){ 
    alert($(this).val());  
});
```

Thanks&Regards

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Maybe your `.del` element doesn't exist when you add the handler

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on("click", ".del", function(){ 
    alert($(this).val());  
});
```

Explanation:

When you call `$(".del").on("click",function(){ ... });`, the event is "bound" to all `.del` that exist **right now**.

As you are adding those through Ajax, though, they are still to exist. By binding the event to the `document` (with `$(document).on("click", ".del", function(){ ...`), all clicks on existing and future `.del` will be caught.

Comment: Ya i tried like this also

    $(document).on("click",".del",function(){
    alert($(this).val());
    });

But its not working

Comment: @SrinuM Seems like this should be the answer.. can you elaborate on "not working"? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @SrinuM Does it give any error? It should work, if we are understanding your question precisely.

Comment: Thank you @acdcjunior I used this Its working fine before that i didnt use document..This code is working        $(document).on("click", ".del", function(){ 
    alert($(this).val());  
});